# MySQL Date Format From Fri Jan 10 00:00:00 UTC 1992 to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: mysql

I have a data "Fri Jan 10 00:00:00 UTC 1992" And I want to convert it to 1992-10-01.

I know how to do it with Javascript, but I have no idea how to do it with MySQL

I tried :
`DATE_FORMAT(column, '%d/%m/%Y')`

But it's return null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select date_format(str_to_date("Fri Jan 10 00:00:00 UTC 1992","%a %b %d %H:%i:%s UTC %Y"),"%Y-%m-%d");
```

First you need str_to_date, using `"%a %b %d %H:%i:%s UTC %Y"` to get a date, after that you can format the date using date_format in the desired format.

[These specifiers shown in the following table may be used in the format string.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)